# When testing POST (create mongo entries), how to delete entries in DB w/ Jmeter after testing, if you don't have DELETE endpoints?

Tags: mongodb, post, jmeter

I'm sure I can write an easy script that simply drops the entire collection from the database but that seems very clumsy as a long term solution.

Currently, we don't have delete endpoints that actually DELETE, we have PUT endpoints that mark the entry as "DONT SHOW/REMOVED" and another "undelete endpoint" that restores the viewing since we technically don't want to delete any data in our implementation of this medical database, for liability purposes.

Does Jmeter have a way where I can make it talk to Mongo and delete? I know there is a deprecated way to talk to mongo via Jmeter but not sure about any modern solutions.

Since I can't add unused code into the repo, does this mean the only solution is for me to make a "extra endpoint" outside of the repo that Jmeter can access to delete each entry?

Seems like a viable solution just not sure if that's the only way to go about it and if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Test Elements were deprecated due to low interest as keeping the MongoDB driver which is being shipped with JMeter up-to-date would require extra effort and the number of users of the MongoDB Test Elements was not that high.

- [Mailing List Message](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-dev/201512.mbox/%3CCAH9fUpZNm%3DcWo5Pv-XQfWuNkxgLp7UwmMDZVVRFRF7jEogMUWw%40mail.gmail.com%3E)
- [Associated JMeter issue](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58772)

However given you don't test MongoDB per se and plan to use JMeter MongoDB elements only for setup/teardown actions I believe you can go ahead.

You can get MongoDB test elements back by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
not_in_menu
```

This will "unhide" [MongoDB Source Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Source_Config_(DEPRECATED)) and [MongoDB Script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script_(DEPRECATED)) elements which you will be able to use for cleaning up the DB. See [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter) for more information, sample queries, tips and tricks.